# ElasticSearch: find multiple unique values in array with complex objects

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Suppose there is an index with documents following a structure like:

```
{
    "array": [
        {
            "field1": 1,
            "field2": 2
        },
        {
            "field1": 3,
            "field2": 2
        },
        {
            "field1": 3,
            "field2": 2
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to define a query that returns documents having multiple unique values for a field?

For the example above, the query searching on ***field2*** would not return the document because all have the same value, but searching on ***field1*** would return it because it has values 1 and 3.

The only thing I can think of is to store the unique values in the parent object and then query for its length, but, as it seems trivial, I'd hope to solve it without having to change the structure to something like:

```
{
    "arrayField1Values" : [1, 3],
    "arrayField2Values" : [2]
    "array": [
        {
            "field1": 1,
            "field2": 2
        },
        {
            "field1": 3,
            "field2": 2
        },
        {
            "field1": 3,
            "field2": 2
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Thanks for anybody that can help!

Comment: You want to return a field if it value appears only once in a document. So if a field is present in  multiple document don't return it or if it is present in all documents then don't return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch was to go with a `nested` datatype but then I realized you could do a simple distinct count on the array-values of fields 1 and 2 using [`query scripts`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) and [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
PUT array

POST array/_doc
{
  "array": [
    {
      "field1": 1,
      "field2": 2
    },
    {
      "field1": 3,
      "field2": 2
    },
    {
      "field1": 3,
      "field2": 2
    }
  ]
}

GET array/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "field1_is_unique": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "def uniques = doc['array.field1'].stream().distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()); return uniques.length > 1 ;",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_field1": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "field2_is_unique": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "def uniques = doc['array.field2'].stream().distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()); return uniques.length > 1 ;",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits_field2": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding separate aggregations for whether `field1` or `field2` included unique value counts > 1:

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "field1_is_unique" : {
      "doc_count" : 1,
      "top_hits_field1" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 1,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : 1.0,
          "hits" : [
            {
              "_index" : "array",
              "_type" : "_doc",
              "_id" : "WbJhgnEBVBaNYdXKNktL",
              "_score" : 1.0,
              "_source" : {
                "array" : [
                  {
                    "field1" : 1,
                    "field2" : 2
                  },
                  {
                    "field1" : 3,
                    "field2" : 2
                  },
                  {
                    "field1" : 3,
                    "field2" : 2
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "field2_is_unique" : {
      "doc_count" : 0,
      "top_hits_field2" : {
        "hits" : {
          "total" : {
            "value" : 0,
            "relation" : "eq"
          },
          "max_score" : null,
          "hits" : [ ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps.